# Can I pass a json object as value for a cli flag in go?

Tags: go

I am using `urfave/cli` for my go program and I would like to have a cli flag that reads a json value like this one:

```
{"name":"foo","surname":"var"}
```

I am currently reading that variable as a `cli.StringFlag` which returns a `string`. Then, I was planning to `json.Unmarshall` it but it does not work. The problem is that the returned `string` by the cli library is like this:

```
[{name foo} {surname var}]
```

which is not a json anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this? Note that if it returned a simple map, that would work too

Comment: A shell is going to parse the quotes strings before it gets passed to your program. You must escape those to pass the json in as an argument. This is the same for any program called from a shell, it has nothing to do with Go or the `cli` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Linux, try to pass the paramaters with shell escape

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "{\"name\":\"foo\",\"surname\":\"var\"}"
```

in go program, just marshal this string parameter

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the shell (bash, ksh, csh, zsh, ...) interprets

```bash
{"name":"foo","surname":"var"}
```

as a sequence of *bareword* and *quoted word* tokens:

| Token Type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| bareword | `{` |
| quoted word | `name` |
| bareword | `:` |
| quoted word | `foo` |
| bareword | `,` |
| quoted word | `surname` |
| bareword | `:` |
| quoted word | `var` |
| bare word | `}` |

As it happens, a comma (`,`) is a shell *operator*, used for arithmetic, and that essentially gets discarded (at least in zsh, what I use).

The whole is then spliced together to get

```
name:foo surname:var
```

You can see this in action by opening your shell and executing the command

```bash
echo {"name":"foo","surname":"var"}
```

If, however, you quote your JSON document with single quotes (`'`):

```bash
echo '{"name":"foo","surname":"var"}'
```

You'll get what you might expect:

```
{"name":"foo","surname":"var"}
```

Note, however, that this will fail if the text in your JSON document contains a literal apostrophe/single quote (`'`, U+0027), so you'd want to replace all  such occurrences within the JSON document with `\,` to escape them.